# How can I set my external monitor as primary monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-monitor

I’m new to Ubuntu (18.04 btw) and Linux in general, in fact this is my first post on the forum, and at the moment I’m having an exceptionally frustrating problem. For the last couple of months my laptops screen (running windows) has been cracked so I would connect it to a monitor and work away. However, recently, in order to pursue a business endeavour I have switched to Linux. As many of you may know, however, the default setting for an external monitor is to mirror, therefore rendering my monitor useless. I can’t even log in as all I see is a purple background on my monitor and my laptop screen is so badly damaged that nothing is visible. I have tried switching the primary monitor using xrandr but I get the message “can’t open display” whenever I do so. I haven’t set up an X server and XORG is not a recognized command so I must not have X11 installed. Is X11 necessary? Are there any keyboard shortcuts? Am I using xrandr wrong? Of course, it would be easy to fix this problem should I be able to get past the login screen and access settings, but currently, that’s not possible. If there were any tips anybody would have for setting up xrandr or any other command lines I could use in the terminal for Ubuntu to be able to switch my external monitor to my primary monitor so that I could actually use my computer that would be very much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear for me, but I can imagine that your built-in display is brocken and now you want to mirror the screen to an external monitor.

1) The easiest way would be to install your harddrive into an other computer and do the settings via xrandr and run this command also during startup. Then change HDD back to broken laptop.

2) Are you able to login? After boot just press twice enter key and write your password. You can access the settings page via right mouse click on external monitor and try there to change the monitor.

Comment: Sadly I don’t have another computer with Linux, the other computer in my place is my roommates and he would strongly object to having Linux on his computer. However, I did press enter twice on my laptop and I put in my password. I’m logged in but I can only see about a tenth of the screen in the top left and a little in the top right and on my external monitor all I can see is the desktop background. I don’t know how I’m going to be able to use my laptop if my external monitor is only showing my background and nothing else...

Comment: That you can log in is good. Just right mouse click -> Change Background -> Scroll down until Devices -> Displays -> Display Mode -> Mirror

Comment: Btw., just changing the harddisk should not destroy the windows installation of the second computer

Comment: If you are logged in you can also use the terminal to change the screen. Just open a terminal via keys "alt" + "ctrl" + "t" and then print "xrandr" and run command. This will output the available screen ports, e.g. LVDS-1 is the laptop screen and VGA-1 is the port for external monitor (could be also HDMI-1, ...). You can mirror the screen with command "xrandr --output VGA-1 --same-as LVDS-1". This will mirror between Laptop screen and VGA output. Names and outputs are depending on your system.

Comment: That’s absolutely fantastic, thanks a million, you’re a lifesaver! The first method about changing background worked perfectly, thanks 

Comment: @Mr.Michael.Schulze You should post that as an answer :) Ping me when you've added, and I'll give it a upvote :)

Comment: @vidarlo done, please upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut key for changing Display Mode (screen mirroring) is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Laptop's primary display was busted.
Following were the steps that got Gnome to display login screen in the VGA or HDMI output.(Not treat the LVDS as primary).

Step-1:
Xorg.conf changed /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "lvds monitor"
    Option "ignore" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "VGA monitor"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
        Option "Monitor-LVDS1" "lvds monitor"
        Option "Monitor-VGA1" "VGA monitor"
        Option "Monitor-HDMI1" "HDMI monitor"
EndSection
```

Step-2: /etc/gdm/custom.conf
GDM requires an additional change to use the xorg.conf.

Uncommented the WaylandEnable=false

```
   # Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
    WaylandEnable=false
```

Step-3:
I also have the following in /etc/gdm/Init/Default
(at the top, just after the path setup)

```
`/usr/bin/xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
/usr/bin/xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --primary`
```

Step-4: (Only required, if you care about getting init script prints on the preferred display)
In grub command line disable LVDS1 and enable VGA1.
in /etc/default/grub

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cl-swap rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap video=LVDS1:d video=VGA1:e"`

Then re-install grub (grub2-mkconfig, followed by grub2-install )

Comment: Excelent info. Thank you very much. I can use my laptop while the laptop replacement display is deliverd :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in, just right mouse click on "Extended monitor", then

> Change Background -> Scroll down until Devices -> Displays -> Display Mode -> Mirror

There you will be able to set the necessary monitor setting.

If you are logged in you can also use the terminal to change the screen. Just open a terminal via keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and then print `xrandr` and run command. This will output the available screen ports, e.g. **LVDS-1** is the laptop screen and **VGA-1** is the port for external monitor (could be also HDMI-1, ...).

You can mirror the screen with command `xrandr --output VGA-1 --same-as LVDS-1`. This will mirror between Laptop screen and VGA output. Names and outputs are depending on your system.